# data not appear in listview till i scroll it

Tags: android, android-listview

first record content appear and the other records not appear untill i scroll the list,So if this list has 3 records which mean that i can't scroll so the first record content only appeared 
[image: not show the other two record's content]

**reocrd XML**

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <RelativeLayout 
>     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     android:background="#ffffffff">
> ```

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Basket ID: "
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:id="@+id/basketIDt"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textColor="@color/abc_input_method_navigation_guard"
    android:paddingTop="30dp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="text"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:id="@+id/basketID"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/basketIDt"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textColor="@color/abc_input_method_navigation_guard"
    android:paddingTop="30dp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:text="text"
    android:id="@+id/description"
    android:layout_below="@+id/basketID"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```

> 

**listview Activity**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="@color/abc_search_url_text_normal"
tools:context="com.example.pc_orbit.myapplication.Employee.BasketList">



        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:id="@+id/lv">
        </ListView>


<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Scan QRCode"
    android:background="@color/button_material_dark"
    android:id="@+id/scan"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textColor="#fffffb6b" />
```

> ListAdapter

```
public class BasketListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<BasketRecord> {
LayoutInflater mInflater;
Context context;
TextView basketID;
TextView description;
String latitude, longitude;
String citizenEmail;
String basketIDString ,descriptionString;
private List<BasketRecord> items = new ArrayList<BasketRecord>();

public BasketListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<BasketRecord> items) {
    super(context, resource, items);
    this.context = context;
    this.items= items;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (null == convertView) {
        RelativeLayout view = (RelativeLayout) RelativeLayout.inflate(this.context,
                R.layout.basketsrecord, null);
        Log.d("SeenDroid", String.format("Get view %d", position));

        TextView id = new TextView(view.getContext());
        description= new TextView(view.getContext());

        latitude = this.items.get(position).getLatitude();
        longitude = this.items.get(position).getLongitude();
        citizenEmail= this.items.get(position).getCitizenEmail();
        basketIDString =this.items.get(position).getBasketID();
        descriptionString=this.items.get(position).getDescription();

        view.addView(id);
        view.addView(description);
        return view;
    } else {
        RelativeLayout view = (RelativeLayout) convertView;
        basketID = (TextView) view.getChildAt(1);
        description= (TextView) view.getChildAt(2);

        basketID.setText(this.items.get(position).getBasketID());
        description.setText(this.items.get(position).getDescription());

        latitude = this.items.get(position).getLatitude();
        longitude = this.items.get(position).getLongitude();
        citizenEmail= this.items.get(position).getCitizenEmail();
        basketIDString = this.items.get(position).getBasketID();
        descriptionString=this.items.get(position).getDescription();

        return convertView;
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the java code related to your list, i mean an adapter or a list

Comment: @UrielUVD I paste it (Y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not setting the data when convert view is null.  Which it would be in the first few passes.  You only set it in the else condition.  One quick fix would be to set the convert view to the view that you are creating instead of returning it at the end of your `if` and then get rid off the `else` (not whats in it) and keep the remaining code.

It would look something like this

```
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (null == convertView) {
            RelativeLayout view = (RelativeLayout) RelativeLayout.inflate(this.context,
                R.layout.basketsrecord, null);
            Log.d("SeenDroid", String.format("Get view %d", position));

            TextView id = new TextView(view.getContext());
            description = new TextView(view.getContext());
            //I am not sure what your logic was here so I just left it in
            latitude = this.items.get(position).getLatitude();
            longitude = this.items.get(position).getLongitude();
            citizenEmail = this.items.get(position).getCitizenEmail();
            basketIDString = this.items.get(position).getBasketID();
            descriptionString = this.items.get(position).getDescription();

            view.addView(id);
            view.addView(description);
            convertView = view;
        }
        RelativeLayout view = (RelativeLayout) convertView;
        basketID = (TextView) view.getChildAt(1);
        description = (TextView) view.getChildAt(2);

        basketID.setText(this.items.get(position).getBasketID());
        description.setText(this.items.get(position).getDescription());

        latitude = this.items.get(position).getLatitude();
        longitude = this.items.get(position).getLongitude();
        citizenEmail = this.items.get(position).getCitizenEmail();
        basketIDString = this.items.get(position).getBasketID();
        descriptionString = this.items.get(position).getDescription();

        return convertView;
       }
```

Note this is only a quick fix.  You should probably clean it to make more readable/reduce lines of code

Comment: Thanks you too much, Appreciate your effort ^_^

Answer (score 0):

A will advice you to use BaseAdapter instead ArrayAdapter, some methods whill help to count items and get id dinamically;

And to use 'Holders'

```
class viewHolderItem{
   TextView id;
   TextView description;
}

public class itemAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
   Activity activity;
   ArrayList<Item> listItems;

    public itemAdapter(Activity activity,ArrayList<Item> listItems){
        this.activity=activity;
        this.listItems=listItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
    //it´s recomended to use an identifiyer for each item on list 
    //
    //return listItems.get(position).getItemId();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        final viewHolderItem viewhold;

        if(vi == null|| !(vi.getTag() instanceof viewHolderItem)) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) actividad.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.basketsrecord,null);
            viewhold=new viewHolderItem();
            viewhold.id=(TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.basketID);
            viewhold.description=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.description);
            //all other view elements of your xml
            //...
        }
        else{
            viewhold = (viewHolderItem)vi.getTag();
        }

        final Item item = listItems.get(position);
        viewhold.id.setText(item.getBasketID());
        viewhold.description.setText(item.getDescription);
        //all other attributes of your object
        //..

        return (vi);
    }

}
```